# Having an issue where I am not sure where to put my finally block

Tags: java

I am not sure where to put my finally block in the linked class I am working on.
I am a beginner so I am still very new to this.

https://pastebin.com/Bu0k6NtL

```
public class CrimesArray {
    
static int columns;
static int row;
String[][]  crime2DArray;  

   public void saveFileTo2DArray(String commandArgs) {

        crime2DArray = new String[row][columns]; //Constructs Array
        String fileLine; //Variable to hold tokens in
        int i=0; //Variable to increment minCapacity

        try {
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(commandArgs)); //A reader to read the commandArgs file and this reader is put into a buffered reader for efficiency
            while ((fileLine = inputStream.readLine()) != null) { //While there is still lines to be read
                addTo2DArray(fileLine.split(","), ++i); //Passes in a String array where it splits every "," and a counter to increment minCapacity
            }
        
        
  //Add's the files contents to a 2D array, it does this by incrementally building our crime2DArray and assigning tempArrays values to it  
    public void addTo2DArray(String[] tmpArray, int minCapacity) {
        if((minCapacity > row)) {
            row = (row * 3)/2 + 1;
            String[][] newArray = new String[row][columns];
            for(int i=0; i<crime2DArray.length; i++) {
                for(int j=0; j<crime2DArray[i].length; j++) {
                    newArray[i][j]=crime2DArray[i][j];
                }
            }
            crime2DArray = newArray;
        }
        crime2DArray[minCapacity-1] = tmpArray;
    }
```

Comment: That would depend on what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: As things stand, there's only one `try` statement, and thus only one place a `finally` block could possibly go.

Comment: I created an array class for an application that will read an excel file containing data related to the US. Crime statistics from 1994-2013. I have two other classes, one to control the outprint and my main class.

Comment: @MarshalKitty - I think Scott means *"what you are trying to accomplish with / in the `finally` block"*.   But I think you are *probably* better off using the Java 8+ "try with resource" feature: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Answer (score -1):

Here is a guide for try / finally syntax in Java language: [Java: try + finally](https://programming.guide/java/try-finally.html)